# Understanding formula for projection of a vector onto a line

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

The formula for projection of a vector 'b' on line represented by vector 'a' is given as the following in
[Linear algebra and its applications by Gilbert Strang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufea.png)

But why is that after finding the scalar 'x-cap' in the derivation, it is multiplied with the vector representing the line i.e. 'a' and not the unit vector along the line i.e. 'a/||a||'?

Could anyone please explain this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deriving $\hat x=\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$, the author starts by assuming that $\hat x$ is the coefficient that is needed for $\hat xa$ to be the point of projection. He could've said that he wanted $\hat x\frac{a}{\|a\|}$ to be this point instead, but then the formula for $\hat x$ would look different to compensate for this (it would've been $\hat x=\frac{a^Tb}{\|a\|}$ instead).

Since he is assuming from the start that he wants $p=\hat xa$, then that is what he gets in the end. Regardless of which assumption you start with, however, you do get
$$
p=\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}a
$$
in the end, as the denominator is either $a^Ta$ from the original derivation, or it is $\|a\|\cdot \|a\|=a^Ta$ from the alternative derivation.

Comment: Oh, I was messing up with the formula ∥a∥⋅∥a∥=aTa as ∥a∥=aTa .. Thanks a lot!!